# Can OpenSSL verify and recover files signed by Crypto++ with RSA-PSSR?

Tags: c++, openssl, crypto++

The background of this is that I'm going to be given a binary file that's been signed using CryptoPP, with the signature included in the file, and the public key, and I want to be able to verify the file and extract the data (without its signature) into another file.

The code that's used to do this with Crypto++ is relatively trivial, but I've been looking around and can't find anything similar. Everything I've looked at seems to be messages where the signature is separate, but I'm not sure how I work out where, in the file, to pull the signature out.

The reason I want to do this is that, given I have a need for OpenSSL for other reasons, I don't want to have to also include Crypto++ in my application if I don't have to.

The existing verification code is like this:

```
const char *key = kPublicKey;  // hex encoded public key

CryptoPP::StringSource f( key, true, new CryptoPP::HexDecoder);
CryptoPP::RSASS< CryptoPP::PSSR, CryptoPP::SHA1 >::Verifier verifier(f);

CryptoPP::FileSource( packageFilename.toStdString().c_str(), true,
                      new CryptoPP::SignatureVerificationFilter(
                          verifier,
                          new CryptoPP::FileSink( recoveredFilename.toStdString().c_str()),
                          CryptoPP::SignatureVerificationFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION | CryptoPP::SignatureVerificationFilter::PUT_MESSAGE )
                    );
```

Which, as I said, looks trivial but, presumably, there's a lot going on under the hood. Essentially that's given the name of a file that includes the content AND the signature, and a "verifier" which incorporates the public key, and checks if the file content is correct and produces a copy of the file without the signature in it.

What I want to do, then, is replicate this using OpenSSL, but I'm not sure whether there are functions in OpenSSL that will let me just pass the whole file and public key and let it work out where the signature is itself, or if I need to pull the signature out of the file somehow (it's stored at the end of the file!), then pass the file content bit by bit into EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate, then pass the signature into EVP_DigestVerifyFinal function.

Any help would be very gratefully appreciate.

**UPDATE**
I'm new to digital signing, so may have missed the significance of PSSR here. After some further research I now understand that the idea of PSSR is that the signature *contains* the message. It may be that the whole of the above could be summarised to:

*Given a public key, and a PSSR signature generated using Crypto++, is it possible to verify the message and extract the original data using OpenSSL?*

From the files (signatures) I've looked at, that have been generated by Crypto++ using its PSSR implementation, it looks like the data isn't changed; it just has extra stuff added at the end (the SIGNATURE_AT_END flag is used). I am struggling to find any reference to PSSR/PSS-R and OpenSSL using Google.

Comment: Use public key to decyrpt, then use signature to validate the file contents.

Comment: The file contents are not encrypted; only signed.

Comment: @sweenish I've added extra content based on further research into what is happening here. Please take a look and see if it makes a difference to your original comment. Thanks.

Comment: It's been awhile since I've messed with crypto-anything. At a high level, the answer is yes so long as both libraries support the same methods. Both definitely suppport RSA, but the PSSR padding is one I'm not sure of. I am betting that OpenSSL supports it, but I've always found their documentation to be a bit lacking.

Comment: @sweenish Thanks for that. I agree with the documentation issue. Unfortunately I've spent hours, if not days, searching online for any evidence that PSS-R can be done with OpenSSL with no luck. PSS, yes, but not PSS-R. Having read some of the Crypto++ documentation too, I even wonder whether their implementation is standard.